# JSONObject to Java representation

Tags: java, android, json

I am sending a request to a server and retrieving a JSON response in the format below. How do I convert it to Java format. Thanks in advance

```
{"customers":{"788488":77,"280460":78},"errors":[]}
```

Comment: You should yous JSONObject in java

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use POJO classes checkout this website : [JSON schema to pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Usage : Select source type **JSON** , and annotation style **None**

Also you can look my answer for information about converting json response to POJO with `Gson`, in this option select annotation style **Gson** : [Convert JSON to POJO with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582247/org-json-jsonexception-value-10-07526-at-0-of-type-java-lang-double-cannot-be-c/36583337#36583337)

More information : [How to create a POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the java classes something like this:

```
public class Main {    
     private Customer customers;
     private List<Object> errors = new ArrayList<Object>();
     // getters/setters    
}

public class Customer {
     private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     // getters/setters
}
```

Since, I do not know about what type error is, so can not really tell, what exactly it is. Now the received JSON (if follows the provided rules (i.e. naming conventions etc)) will be converted to the response in appropriate fields.